# Fail to create new Android NDK project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to learn how to write code in Android NDK. 
I open the 'android studio guide' and on the 'create new ndk project' I follow the instruction.

I just create new project and add support for C++ code and that's it .. all the IDE code is in red and nothing can be compile.

Can't find any problem and I don't know what to do.

[image]

Tried to sync by clicking 'Try again' in first - and still fail.

The error message is:

> CMake Error at
>   C:/Users/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:40
>   (cmake_minimum_required):   CMake 3.6.0 or higher is required.  You
>   are running version 3.4.1 Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   C:/Users/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/cmake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98
>   (include)   CMakeLists.txt CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set,
>   after EnableLanguage CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after
>   EnableLanguage
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! Build command failed. Error while executing process
>   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe with arguments
>   {-HC:\WORKSPACE\Android\Practice\NDK\Practice_001\app
>   -BC:\WORKSPACE\Android\Practice\NDK\Practice_001\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi
>   -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Rn\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\WORKSPACE\Android\Practice\NDK\Practice_001\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmake\bin\ninja.exe
>   -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
>   -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions} CMake Error at
>   C:/Users/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:40
>   (cmake_minimum_required):   CMake 3.6.0 or higher is required.  You
>   are running version 3.4.1 Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   C:/Users/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/cmake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98
>   (include)   CMakeLists.txt CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set,
>   after EnableLanguage CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after
>   EnableLanguage
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The yellow banner has "Gradle project sync failed". When you click "Try Again", what happens? What error messages appear in the Messages tool?

Comment: attached the error on the 'try again'

Comment: open Android Studio's SDK manager to check your CMake version. if it is 3.4, then you could update it there as @CommonsWare pointed out. if it is 3.6 already, possible you have CMake 3.4 installed separated on your system and it is inside $PATH? if it is, remove it from $PATH try it again. eager to see your result. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the "**Try again**" in yellow banner. If you got the error still probably problem is with you do not have necessary **library packages** in your `build.gradle` file. Check if you have added necessary [Support Library Packages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html) in your `build.gradle` file. If doesn't then add it and "**rebuild**" your project.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is:

```
CMake 3.6.0 or higher is required. You are running version 3.4.1
```

I do not know whether you have your own CMake installation or you are attempting to use one that comes from Android Studio. My guess is that you have your own CMake installation. If so, upgrade it to 3.6.0 or higher.

Comment: The log suggests that this cmake is part of Android sdk. It should be upgradable in SDK manager of Android Studio.